# Google Visualization Dashboard w/ Diff Chart

Tags: google-visualization

I would like to create a Google Visualization Dashboard that has a Diff Chart as one of my displays.  As with any dashboard, I would like the filters to control what data is displayed in the charts.  Is this possible?  I cannot seem to wrap my head around it.

Comment: Do you have other charts aside from the diff chart?

Comment: Yes, I would like to.  But if it is possible with only the diff chart, then I will have to live with that.

Comment: Having a second chart (that isn't a diff chart) may actually make this easier.  I'll give it some thought and try to come up with an example.

Comment: Oh, okay.  I would not have thought that, but I that would be ideal!

Comment: Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/VPG2L/

Comment: @asgallant, do you know if there is a way to add another chart (that is not a Diff chart) to the dashboard that is based on only one of the datasets (e.g. the "newData" in your jsfiddle)?  In your example, the dashboard draws on the "diffData," which makes total sense for the Diff Chart.  But I'd like to add a line chart that is only based on the "newData."  However, it seems that I must choose one dataset when I do dashboard.draw(???). Is there a way for the dashboard to reference one dataset, but certain charts reference another dataset?

Comment: Use the `view` parameter of the `ChartWrapper` to set the columns a chart uses.  The diff data calculation changes the role type of the data, so you have to change it back in the view to get the charts to draw correctly.  See an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/VPG2L/1/